# R questions - how to select multiple rows containing certain strings in multiple columns?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, delete-row

Using R, I am analyzing a longitudinal dataset. The following table serves as an example. I would like to

1. select multiple rows containing certain strings (e.g., A1, A13, B1, B2) in multiple columns (dg1, dg2, dg3, dg4), while keeping other columns (e.g., agegroup).
2. assign subjects with the selected rows to group A and those with the unselected rows to group B.

What would be the best solution to this? Thank you in advance!

```
id  dg1 dg2 dg3 dg4 agegroup
1   A1  F1  D1  B3  1
1   B3  A13 C1  B5  2
2   B5  D1  B1  B6  1
2   C1  C1  B4  B2  2
2   D1  C1  B5  A1  3
3   D1  B4  D1  C2  1
4   E1  B1  G1  C3  2
4   E2  B7  F1  S13 3
5   F1  B3  D1  B2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you would like to check if any of the columns dg1 to dg4 contain the desired pattern, if so the row has class "A" else "B".

```
> pat=c("A1","A13","B1","B2")
> ifelse(rowSums(mapply(`==`,df[grep("dg",colnames(df))],pat))>0,"A","B")
[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "A"
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I might have done something wrong but when I ran your R scripts, I got an error message, indicating "argument "no" is missing, with no default." Instead, I tried the following R scripts and they worked but I am unsure if this is the best solution and I am still trying to figure out the second question. Thank you!                                
d.sub <- d %>% filter_at(vars(dg1, dg2, dg3, dg4), any_vars(. %in% c("A1" ,"A13", "B1", "B2")))

Comment: @Grace This code works for the data you provided. If you ran it on your data and it doesn't work then your data must be different. You should adapt the code to match your new data.